# proving that a function exits with derivative of $\cos(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to prove that a function exists that in all real numbers is differentiable and its derivative is equal to:

$$
f(x)= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \cos ( \frac{1}{x} ) & x \neq 0 \\
        0 & x=0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

I've been trying to solve this for a while. Can someone give a hint to how I should approach this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $F(x)=-x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$, then $F'(x)=\cos\left(\frac1x\right)-2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $F$ which is defined for $x\neq 0$ by
$$
F(x) =  - x^2 \sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) + 2\int_0^x {t\sin \left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right)dt} 
$$
and by $F(0)=0$ for $x=0$. It is easy to check that $F'(x)$ exists and is $\cos(1/x)$ whenever $x\neq 0$. Now
$$
F'(0) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{F(x) - F(0)}}{{x - 0}} =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} x\sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{x}\int_0^x {t\sin \left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right)dt},
$$
and since
$$
\left| {x\sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right| \le |x| \; \text{ and } \; \left| {\frac{2}{x}\int_0^x {t\sin \left( {\frac{1}{t}} \right)dt} } \right| \le \frac{2}{|x|}\int_0^{|x|} {tdt}  = |x|,
$$
we see that $F'(0) = 0$.